# Can I exclude a post by meta key using pre_get_posts function?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, pre-get-posts, featured-post

I see many people prefer to use `pre_get_posts` hook instead of `query_posts`. The code below works and shows all posts which have meta key "featured"

```
function show_featured_posts ( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
       $query->set( 'meta_key', 'featured' );
       $query->set( 'meta_value', 'yes' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_featured_posts' );
```

But I want the posts which have '`featured`' meta_key to be **excluded** from the main query. Is there an easy way for this?

Answer (score 46):

> I see many people prefer to use pre_get_posts hook instead of query_posts

Yay!

So `pre_get_posts` filters a [`WP_Query` object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) which means *anything* you could do via `query_posts()` you can do via `$query->set()` and `$query->get()`. In particular we can make use of the `meta_query` attribute (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)):

```
$meta_query = array(
                 array(
                    'key'=>'featured',
                    'value'=>'yes',
                    'compare'=>'!=',
                 ),
);
$query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
```

But.. this replaces the original 'meta query' (if it had one). So unless you want to completely replace the original meta query, I suggest:

```
//Get original meta query
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

//Add our meta query to the original meta queries
$meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'=>'featured',
                    'value'=>'yes',
                    'compare'=>'!=',
                );
$query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
```

This way we add our meta query alongside existing meta queries.

You may/may not want to set the `relation` property of `$meta_query` to `AND` or `OR` (to return posts that satisfy all, or at least one, meta queries).

* ***Note:*** This type of query will return posts with the 'featured' meta key, but whose value is not `yes`. It will not include posts where the 'featured' meta key doesn't exist. [You'll be able to do this in 3.5](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18158).

Comment: So there is no way to check if a meta_key for a post exists or not / is empty or not? I'll have to wait 3.5. then. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I will simply create a meta box with `Yes` and `No` options and 'No' will be selected by default. When I want to feature a post I will select `Yes`. However, I want last 5 posts to stay featured and others go on to display on the main query. I dont want to go back and change the selection everytime so I have to find a way to exclude only most recent 5 posts only. I see many similar questions on stackexchange and there should be an easy way to manage those featured posts. (a way that doesn't affect general performance, doesn't create lots of queries or require mixed sql queries)

Comment: BTW I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to create an extra meta_key with `Yes` or `No` value for all posts. It would be great to exclude those posts which simply lack the `featured` key.

Comment: This function just broke down on my site after upgrading to PHP 7 throwing an `Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings` error as the original `meta_query` was coming back as null. You can get around it by falling back to an empty array if none exists switching out `$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');` for `$meta_query = ( is_array( $query->get('meta_query') ) ) ? $query->get('meta_query') : [];`.

Answer (score 2):

I want to post my temporary solution for featured posts in case some people may make use of it. I don't use `pre_get_posts` hook here but not `query_posts` either. The problem is that I have to play with the main query and have to run a piece of sql query.
I would be happy if any experts could check the code and let me know whether it's OK and will not cause any performance issues. It will also be great if anyone has a better approach and share it with us.

Create featured posts query

```
<?php 

$featured_query = new WP_query( array(
    'meta_key'       =>'featured', 
    'meta_value'     =>'yes', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'no_found_rows'  => true
    )
);

while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 

    $featured_query->the_post(); 
    //Stuff...

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); 

?>
```

Create the main query, exclude the posts which has the featured meta_key, limit the exclusion to 5 most recent posts and show all others.

```
<?php 

$excludeposts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'featured' AND meta_value != '' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 0, 5" );

$main_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__not_in' => $excludeposts, 
    'paged' => $paged 
    ) 
);  

while ($main_query->have_posts()) : 

    $main_query->the_post();
    //Stuff...

endwhile;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In response @Carlisle, if you want exclude the most 5 recent posts marked featured, you could do the following.  Change the posts_per_page to how many you want to exclude, and the meta_query to how you are designating the featured category.

```
function cmp_exclude_featured_posts($query) {
    $exclude = array();  //Create empty array for post ids to exclude
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $featured = get_posts(array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'featured',
                        'value' => '1',
                        'compare' => '==',
                    ),
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => 2
            ));

            foreach($featured as $hide) {
                $exclude[] = $hide->ID;
            }   

            $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude);
        }
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'cmp_exclude_featured_posts' );
```