# Is 'pm' used by core?

Tags: pagination, slug

We've a private messaging system that uses the page slug `pm`. It lists messages.

Recently, we noticed that pagination stopped working on this page. So going to page 2 gives a `page not found` error.

We suspected that WP core might have picked this slug/term in a recent update.

We changed it to `page-pm2.php` and pagination worked fine!

To confirm, I switched to an untouched twentyfifteen theme, created `page-pm.php`, pagination doesn't work. Changed it to `page-whatever.php` and it works.

Have a completely lost my mind or what's going on?

EDIT: Here is the relevant code:

```
// current user id
$currentuser = get_current_user_id();

// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// arguments to filter posts
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'last_activity',

    'post_type' => 'pm',
    'post_status' => 'pm_active',

    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_receiver_id',
            'value'   => $currentuser
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_sender_id',
            'value'   => $currentuser
        )
    )

);

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


// if posts are found
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

// the loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    // do stuff with posts...

// end loop
    endwhile;

    echo '<div class="pag_next">';

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );
    next_posts_link( 'Next', $the_query->max_num_pages );

    echo '</div>';



// clean up after the query and pagination
    wp_reset_postdata();

else:

    echo '<div class="no-results">Your inbox is empty.</div>';

endif;
```

Comment: What is `var_dump(get_queried_object());` when your pages don't paginate?

Comment: @s_ha_dum As you asking me to run var_dump(get_queried_object()); on page 2? To do this successfully, I edited index.php with this code (because the page falls back to it when displaying the *page not found* error) and it gives *NULL*. EDIT: running this on page 1 (that works), I get: http://pastebin.com/BMNwfegJ

Comment: That is a normal page. I assume that is correct? What is the pagination code you are using?

Comment: Why don't you just filter `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes. I have edit my question with the relevant code. Note that I've tested the query with just listing latest 'posts' and pagination doesn't work if page is page-pm.php

Comment: @toscho is correct. Use a filter. You are doing this is a way that is notoriously problematic.

Comment: @toscho I do not know if i'm missing something here, but how do you use `pre_get_posts` on true pages. :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen What is stopping you? I've done that hundreds of times.

Comment: We have dozens of examples for that already. This one is quite clear: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72126/73

Comment: @toscho Basically, I'm hitting a secondary query using wp_query() on a *page*, when I suppose I should have created an archive page with its main query which I would filter using pre_get_posts()? Is this correct? In the current state, it wouldn't make sense to filter the secondary query if you get my grip.

Comment: @ChristineCooper You can filter `pre_get_posts` on almost any frontend view, including a `page`—which isn't a page anymore after you've filtered the query. What you probably **should** do: make `message` a post type and use its archive to display the message list. WordPress will then do all the hard work for you, you just have to filter the list for the current user.