# hide posts with specific meta data from admin page

Tags: post-meta

Does anyone have ideas on how to hide posts which has a metadata with a specific value from admin panel (the posts table which is shown when clicking all posts option from posts tab)
thank you in advance guys

Comment: You can use `pre_get_posts` conjoined with a `meta_query`. `pre_get_posts` runs on front-end and admin-panel.

Comment: thank you really after searching for two days I just found the same solution you proposed with an example here:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72099/can-i-exclude-a-post-by-meta-key-using-pre-get-posts-function